# SWT project on Creme jvm, windows mobile 6.5

Tags: eclipse, jvm, windows-mobile, swt

I am starting a java SWT project with creme 4.12 jvm for a windows mobile 6.5 pocket pc.
I really dont know where to start. could not google out any good documentation or example, just a few questions in forums.

I would like to know:

1. Is there any good docs around that i was unable to find?
2. Do i have to put any extra configuration on eclipse or i can create and build a simple java project, with sdk 1.3.
3. I have included the swt-32.dll as native library in swt.jar

i have tried to run it on the device but it crashes before running.

Sorry for the long question, but i really dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not that much experience with CrEme although I know that some large WM installs use that.

I can do an AWT app in netbeans and run it successfully on a device.

Look for the netbeans mobility pack to start with CrEme and netbeans.

OTOH you can go on with eclipse. Where did you get the swt files from? I found one source here http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/15.

Here is one source I found for an intro to SWT on WM: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-small-cup-of-swt/pocket-PC.html